# Google colaboratory use kaggle, server version 1.5.6 , client version 1.5.4, failed to upgrade

Tags: version, google-colaboratory, kaggle

I want to use the kaggle API in google colaboratory. The client installed is 1.5.4, the server is 1.5.6. After running install and upgrade kaggle via `pip`, the system still calls the version 1.5.4

I have tried installing and upgrading with pip the kaggle package. Doesn't work. I tried restarting the session/runtime as well.

```
!pip install kaggle/pip install kaggle --upgrade
```

```
Requirement already up-to-date: kaggle in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (1.5.6)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: requests in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from kaggle) (2.21.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: certifi in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from kaggle) (2019.9.11)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: tqdm in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from kaggle) (4.28.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: python-dateutil in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from kaggle) (2.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: python-slugify in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from kaggle) (4.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: urllib3<1.25,>=1.21.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from kaggle) (1.24.3)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: six>=1.10 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from kaggle) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from requests->kaggle) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from requests->kaggle) (2.8)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: text-unidecode>=1.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (from python-slugify->kaggle) (1.3)
```

```
!kaggle -v
```

```
Kaggle API 1.5.4
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Ah, this is indeed a strange state.

The fix: `!pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall --no-deps kaggle`

The underlying problem: we install both py2 and py3 packages, and (for historical reasons) the py2 packages are installed second. `kaggle` is a wrapper installed by the kaggle python package; since we do py2 second, the py2 wrapper is in `/usr/local/bin`, and happens to be an older version.

Comment: Who is "we" when you say "we install"?

Comment: I work on Colab, so "we install" really means "we install when creating the container". :)